# How to access instance variables of synthesized properties from a vendored class

Tags: rubymotion

I am reopening a vendored objective-c class, but i'm struggling with a clean way to be able to access the _username synthesized instance variable in order to not cause infinite recursion. This seems like it should be extremely straightforward but have not yet found a workable solution.

**User.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;

@end
```

**user.rb**

```
# reopens User < NSManagedObjectContext
class User

  def username
   # how do i access _username instance var of User.h ??  
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@_username` ?

Comment: @vacawama yeah, doesn't work, not the same "namespace"

Answer (score 0):

I originally tried `alias_method :original_username, :username` but because they are declared @dynamic and generated at runtime, rubymotion will get an undefined crash for username. After reading [Managed Object Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdAccessorMethods.html) I found an alternative solution.

```
- (NSString *)name
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *myName = [self primitiveName];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    return myName;
}
```